# Where to put Value() in this formula for it to work

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i currently have this formula, which puts out a year(like 2009, 2011, etc.)

```
=IF(ISEMPTY(A2);"";"20"&MID(A2;1;2))
```

Now, i would like the result to be handled as a Value, by adding the formula Value() to the existing formula. However, i have no idea where to add it. Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `=IF(ISEMPTY(A2);"";VALUE("20"&MID(A2;1;2)))`

Comment: `=IF(ISBLANK(A2);"";--("20"&MID(A2;1;2)))`

Comment: isempty() ? what version of excel do you have because the nearest function is isblank()) at least with 365. Another possibility is IF(A2="";"";VALUE("20"&MID(A2;1;2)))

Comment: Or avoid value() completely: IF(A2="";"";("20"&MID(A2;1;2)*1))

Comment: Or perhaps: `=IF(A2="";"";2000+LEFT(A2;2))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISEMPTY(A2);"";VALUE("20"&MID(A2;1;2)))
```

This worked for me, thanks Scott Craner and BigBen

Answer (score 0):

By concatenating "20"**&**MID(A2;1;2) you are creating a Text value.
Since this is your output, add the value conversion to convert the Text in to value.

Like so : Value("20"&MID(A2;1;2))

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use numbers to start with?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",2000 + MID(A3,1,2))
```

Explanation: "20"&... creates a string, while
2000 + ... creates exactly the same thing, but as a number.